How to move numbers on a number line?
I have a Firebird 3 table like this:
MyTable
-------
ID: Integer (auto inc), primary key
Pos: Integer, Unique
Flavor: varchar

Data looks like:
Pos  Flavor
-------------
 1   Chocolate
 2   Vanilla
 3   Strawberry
 4   Butter Pecan
 5   Salted Caramel
 6   Cookie Dough

The user can now change the order of their favorite ice cream flavor in the Pos column. Only one change is permitted at a time.
For example, he would like to move Strawberry from position 3 to position 5. So:
update MyTable 
set Pos = 5 
where Pos = 3

The result should then look like this:
Pos  Flavor
-------------
 1   Chocolate
 2   Vanilla
 3   Butter Pecan
 4   Salted Caramel
 5   Strawberry  
 6   Cookie Dough

Moving should be possible in both directions. If a number greater than the number of data records is specified as the target, e.g. 10 in this case, the new position should be at the end. Here, for example, 6. Gaps in the numbering are not permitted.
After much trial and error with a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, I am now looking for help here.
My code with comments for changing Pos 3 to 5:
(This triggers works only if destination pos is greater than the source pos to keep it simple.)
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER MyTrigger FOR MyTable
ACTIVE BEFORE UPDATE POSITION 0
begin
  if (RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_SESSION', 'MyTable_BI_LOCK') is null) then
  begin

    rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'MyTable_BI_LOCK', true);

    --set Pos 3 to temp pos 999
    update MyTable
    set Pos = 999
    where Pos = old.pos;

    --set Pos 4 to 3 and Pos 5 to 4 to make space for the new 5
    update MyTable bp
    set Pos = (Select NewPos From (SELECT id, row_number() over(order by Pos) as NewPos FROM MyTable) sub Where sub.id = bp.id)
    where (bp.Pos > old.pos) and (bp.Pos <= new.pos);

    rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'MyTable_BI_LOCK', null);

    WHEN ANY DO
    begin
      rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'MyTable_BI_LOCK', null);
      exception;
    end
  end

end

--after the trigger temp pos 999 (was 3) is set to 5

After executing
update MyTable 
set Pos = 5 
where Pos = 3

I get this error:

violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "UNQ_POS" on table "MYTABLE"
Problematic key value is ("POS" = 4)

But if I do not change the pos columns for debugging and only write the new contents of the pos columns in a varchar column, the varchar column contains the correct numbers!

Please show what you tried and explain what didn't work for you, that is: show a [mre] (though I can guess at the problem, because this will cause a recursive firing of the trigger). This is probably better solved using a stored procedure that will swap the items than trying to use a trigger.

I've added my code.

POS don't need to be unique. Remove this constraint and your code will work. But I personally would change the field to DOUBLE_PRECISION and save a lot of updates calculating new POS as an average value of new neighbors (or giving it a good distance from the last position).

Can you also post the DDL of the table (including indexes and constraints)?

I've removed the unique constraint and now it's working. Thanks user13964273
